# Simple way to implement a product buying with paypal

Tags: php, html, paypal

before explaining my problem I would like to clarify that I read a lot of docs on paypal about what I'm searching for but everytime I get lost with tons of features that paypal offers to developers, blowing up my head a bit.

I want to implement a really basic way to buy a product on a PHP website, with a constant price, no shopping or cart, just "add paypal as a payment method" with others that I've implemented. Something like, buy this with paypal, get in a paypal website to login with your credentials, confirm the price of the product, then returning back to the website after the transaction is done and make some database stored procedures (with MySQL) that would mean you bought the product. This product is just a Premium membership on a game, which consists on a flag inside an account stored in a database.

That thing is already done, a system wrriten in PHP that allows users to log in their accounts and choose a payment method and the amount of Money they want to charge in their accounts. Problem is Paypal offers tons of features, and what I'm searching on is a little thingy and I cannot find a concrete example of it, and this is a simple popup (or an external site) that asks to the customer (logged in his paypal account) if they agree (or whatever) with no shopping info or cart.

If anybody can guide me about which doc or page in concrete should I read, or a really basic example, I would appreciate it a lot. This is just for letting people pay with Dollars, there's already a national payment method on this game (CLP, Chilean Peso) and people from outside cannot access to it.

Answer (score 0):

> what I'm searching on is a little thingy and I cannot find a concrete example of it, and this is a simple popup (or an external site) that asks to the customer (logged in his paypal account) if they agree (or whatever) with no shopping info or cart.

I have no idea what that is about, but the rest of your question sounds like you want to implement a basic PayPal checkout. Here is a UI demo pattern of the client-side UI for two versions. One is client-side only, the other uses a server as well for payment setup and capture, which is better for storing things to a database:

- https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
- https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

  The server side portion of the 2nd type of integration (particularly for the paymentset up and capture API calls) is discussed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

  - [Set up the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/)
  - [Capture the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/)

    If the capture is successful, this is when you would write it to your database.

---

If you do choose to implement a server-side integration, then -- once everything is working for the happy path -- don't neglect to implement funding failure error handling: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/ ;  This will allow buyers to choose a different funding instrument if e.g. their first card is declined by the capture attempt